# Creating a graph with weighted edges and vertex properties using Boost Graph library

Tags: c++, boost, graph, shortest-path, adjacency-list

Using boost library, I want to create a graph with directed & weighted edges and vertices having some properties to solve shortest path problem. Actually, it is not a full graph. In pre-process, I can eliminate some of the edges. However, it is not working properly when I do the pre-process. You can say there is problem about your pre-process. But, when I control the cost of path found, I observed that it is different than the sum of the cost of edges! Currently, I am checking edges in pre-process and while adding them in loops, I am controlling whether I flagged the edge "worth to add". Maybe I am doing something work in data structure. Let me know whether there is an appropriate way to introduce the graph.

EDIT:
Here is the code:

```
vector< vector< bool > > is_removed( N );
vector< vector< bool > > in_out( N );
for ( int i = 0; i < N; ++i )
{
   is_removed[i].resize( N, false ); // whether arc(i,j) is removed
   in_out[i].resize( 2, false ); // whether node(i) has an arc: 0 is in, 1 is out
}
.
.
.
.
int say = 0;
vector< bool > add( N, true ); // when i update this, it gives incorrect results
for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
  if ( !in_out[i][0] || !in_out[i][1] )
  {
     add[i] = false;
  }
  else
  {
     num[i] = say;
     say++;
  }
}

int v_last = add_vertices( source_node, add ); 

for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
  if ( add[i] )
  {
     for ( int j = 0; j < N ; j++ )
     {
        if ( i != j && !is_removed[i][j] && add[j] )
        {
           add_edge( num[i], num[j], ESPPRC_Graph_Arc_Prop( a, edge_cost[i][j], Dist[i][j] ), Grph );
           a++;
        }
        else // When I remove this else it gives incorrect results
        {
           add_edge( num[i], num[j], ESPPRC_Graph_Arc_Prop( a, edge_cost[i][j], MAX_VAL ), Grph );
           a++;
        }
     }
  }
}

int add_vertices( const int& source_node, const vector<bool>& add )
{
   Grph.clear();
   int v = 0;
   for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
   {
      if ( add[i] )
      {
          add_vertex( ESPPRC_Graph_Vert_Prop( v, Dem[i], TimeWin[i][0], TimeWin[i][1], ServTime[i] ), Grph );
          v++;
      }
   }

   return v;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a minimal sample? You claim quite a few few fuzzy things in unclear English. If you let the code speak, we might be able to understand a question

Comment: I have just added the code..

Comment: why are we having to make up even the type of adjacency list?! Here's how you do a minimal example: SSCCE.org **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34ba5c62af1260b4)**. Sadly I've expended more energy than this question appears to deserve just putting these loose ends together.